# List of template suggestion used for a node

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I'm building a module that return you an HTML styled node via ajax but I have a question.
I want to add a node suggestion only for this module. How?

So drupal have to check:
Exist [in active theme] ajaxnode.tpl? And ajaxnode--nodetype.tpl? If they don't exist choice the normal drupal suggestion template and render the node.

How can i do this correctly?

Comment: You could use the documentation from https://drupal.org/node/1089656 for template hinting in drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go and get the [Theme developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.  Simply get the element you want to theme and click on it - then you'll get a list of any template files and/or theme functions that were called in the processing of the element you clicked.

> Firebug for Drupal themeing. See the [screenshot and screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561). Note
>   that this module injects markers into the DOM to do its magic. This
>   may cause some themes to behave erratically and less capable browsers
>   may make it worse (especially IE)/. Enable it when needed, and disable
>   it afterwards.

Comment: I need to have the template files's list in the module not in interface..